# Merging Columns and its values in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe df1 , which consists of columns from Var1 to Var10.
Now I have taken a subset of columns as a dataframe df2 from Var5 to Var9, performed some operations and now I have to overwrite df1 with columns from df2.

I want to merge df2 ie var5 to var10 to df1(which also has var5 to var9 columns).

I tried below code:

```
merge(df1,df2,by.x = "",y="")
```

Ideally I have a lot of columns, specifying columns with comma isn't a great way

Comment: It would be great if could provide a reproducible exemple of your problem (with sham data if needed). You can use `dput(mydata)` e.g or more here: [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Using `?merge` it appears you don't need the extra `by.x` or `y` arguments. Moreover `by` uses by default common variable names between data.frames. Thus, provided you don't have duplicates subsetting by Var5:Var9 on the whole data set you could do :

```r
merge(x = df1, y = df2)
```